# SIM808 - Reset from script

Tags: python

I'm working with a SIM808 connected to my RPi by serial using AT commands, from Python.

I need my code to reset the SIM808 card (ie, do the same thing as when the reset button is pressed) at the beginning of the code, but I have not found an AT command for this.

Comment: I doubt that you can do this from the standard input. Usually a reset pin like that is a configured to a physical hardware interrupt that does a hard reset on the device. You may need to look at hooking in another pin.

Comment: I don't know an awful lot about the module, but [this Sim800 series AT manual](http://cristiansteib.github.io/Sim800l/info/SIM800+Series_AT+Command+Manual_V1.09.pdf) includes *AT+CFUN=1,1 can be used to reset module purposely at minimum/full
functionality mode* (3.2.42/p101). I *think* that might reset your module, but it may just be a reset for a particular feature.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure that isn't possible since the actual reset button just sends a signal to the CPU_RST.